# Craftable automatic weapons in the game

Tags: atom-rpg

Before I want to commit on Gun Jesus perk (20% damage ftw) I want to make sure I choose the right perks for the right type of guns (ie pistol/rifle/auto).

My question: Is there any craftable automatic weapons in this game?

Answer (score 0):

**No, at this moment it seems there are no craftable automatic weapons in Atom RPG**.

At first, cross referencing a [couple](https://prodigygamers.com/2018/12/21/atom-rpg-list-of-all-the-crafting-recipes-for-all-items/) [of](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1595760933) [websites](https://atom-rpg.fandom.com/ru/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%82%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B0), I suspected the *samopals* to be (at least semi-) automatic weapons, [as their name suggests](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samopal), but their magazines are too small (see [here](https://atom-rpg.fandom.com/ru/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB), for example).